# How to make an array with size received as arguments in a function in LISP?

Tags: arrays, lisp

I'm trying to create a function that receives a number of lines and columns and makes an array out of it. 
This is what I did

```
(defun create-table (lines columns)
     (make-array '(lines columns)))
```

I thought this is how you make a multidimensional array. But as I call the function `create-table` for example `(create-table 2 2)` this error is given

> MAKE-ARRAY: dimension LINES is not of type `(INTEGER 0
>         (,ARRAY-DIMENSION-LIMIT))

I don't understand, how could it not be an integer? Should I make a cast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you think `'(lines columns)` evaluates to?

Hint: you can create lists with the function `LIST`.

Comment: I want to make a multidimensional array.
`(create-table 2 2)` would make an array as such: 
`#2A((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))` which is what happens when I make `make-array '(2 2))`. I just don't understand why my function `create-table`doesn't do that

Comment: @FriedRike: Ask yourself: What do you think '(lines columns) evaluates to? One more hint: what do you think the quote character does in Lisp?

Comment: the quote character says whatever is in from of it is not to be evaluated. But according to my research, that's how you make a multidimensional array.

Comment: @FriedRike: so `'(lines columns)` is evaluated to `(lines columns)`. This is a list whose first element is the symbol `lines` and the second element is the symbol `columns`. What should `MAKE-ARRAY` do with that? `MAKE-ARRAY` expects a list of numbers, not a list of symbols. A valid array dimension is a fixnum, not a symbol.

Comment: @FriedRike There's a difference between `'(2 3)` and `(let ((lines 2) (columns 3)) '(lines columns))`.

Comment: I think I got it... I have to create a list and pass it as an argument for make-array. as such? `(make-array (list lines columns))`

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your function

Try like this

```
(defun create-table (lines columns)
 (make-array `(,lines ,columns)))
```